# Need help in Regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have input like `"Varchar(10)`, `Number(10)`, `datetime(8)`, `varchar(17)`, `char(3)` at a time one.

I need to extract only text from it. How can I do it in Java?

Lets say I have input `Varchar(50)` and expecting output `Varchar`.

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
String line = "varchar(0)";
String pattern = "\\D{.*}";
// Create a Pattern object 
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
// Now create matcher object. 
Matcher m = r.matcher(line); 
if (m.find( )) { 
  System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) ); 
} else { 
  System.out.println("NO MATCH"); 
}
```

Comment: Is the input a comma separated string, or do you only ever have one of those values at a given point in time?

Comment: String line = "varchar(0)";
        String pattern = "\\D{.*}";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.find( )) {
           System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
        } else {
           System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }

Answer (score 2):

Your group regular expression is in general

```
\w+\(\d+\)
```

and to capture the first part, you can make it into a group

```
(\w+)\(\d+\)
```

Try this function:

```
private final Pattern TYPE_REGEX = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\(\\d+\\)");

public String extractType(String item) {
  Matcher matcher = TYPE_REGEX.matcher(item.trim());
  if(!matcher.matches())
    return null;
  return matcher.group(1);
}
```

**Freebie:**

You might also use a typesafe enum, for your return type, as I think you're dealing with a fixed set of database types

```
private enum Type { VARCHAR, NUMBER, DATETIME, CHAR, ADD_ALL_OTHERS_THAT_APPLY }
private final Pattern TYPE_REGEX = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\(\\d+\\)");

public Type extractType(String item) {
  Matcher matcher = TYPE_REGEX.matcher(item.trim());
  if(!matcher.matches())
    return null;
  return Type.valueOf(matcher.group(1).toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: The solutions seems to be even easier as OP only has already splitted Strings (i.e. it is not a comma separated string but only one item at a time).

Answer (score 0):

I think a regular expression is overkill if you're only dealing with single appearences.

For example:

```
s = val.substring(1, val.indexOf ('('))
```

would do the job. Although this would always expect to see '(' as part of the input string.

Comment: Tidy up: substring(1, val.indexOf('('))  - use indexOf rather than charAt, and also no -1 required, since ending substring is exclusive. Otherwise, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your input string with this regex `"\\(\\d+\\),*"`:

**Sample code:**

```
String str = "Varchar(10), Number(10), datetime(8), varchar(17), char(3)";
String[] parts = str.split("\\(\\d+\\),*");

for (String part : parts)
    System.out.println(part.trim());
```

**Output** (Note that `trim()` is invoked before printing an element.):

```
Varchar
Number
datetime
varchar
char
```

Comment: No I have input as Varchar(10) only what would be regex pattern?

Comment: @user900721 You already have your answer from djjeck: `\w+`, or in java: `String pattern = "\\w+"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
line.replaceAll("\\([^\\)]*\\)","");
```